# Finding the base color of one at 50% opacity

Tags: color, transparency, color-reproduction

I have the color that's the result of another color applied onto a white background with an opacity of 50%. That color has the HEX #b4dcf7. Apologies if I'm missing something simple, but is there an easy way to get what the color would've been if applied at full opacity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain the hex code for a color that isn't 100% opaque?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75874/how-to-obtain-the-hex-code-for-a-color-that-isnt-100-opaque)

Comment: Not that I can tell. That seems to be wanting the color of their normal color at the desired opacity. This would be the opposite. I have a color I know was applied at 50% opacity and I don't know how to obtain what the original color was supposed to be. I apologize if there's something I missed.

Comment: THere are many.... https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113007/how-to-determine-the-equivalent-opaque-rgb-color-for-a-given-partially-transpare - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42176/how-to-determine-the-color-and-opacity-using-the-color-picker-tool -- Explaining what software you have available may make a difference.

Comment: The solution in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/113007/178707 seems like it may be it. The last one (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/42176/178707)  doesn't help as I only have a screenshot of the WIP before my harddrive failed. I'll look into the first, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have consistent color settings in all of your used software and you did not use any software screen color calibration (which makes the rgb numbers in your screenshot unpredictable) you can simply reverse the formula shown in the answers of duplicate candidate that you called "seems like it may be it". For 50% opacity simply double the rgb-numbers of your screenshot color and subtract 255 from the results.

Comment: Color management usually does not affect color blending. Weird huh?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, first convert your hex numbers to RGB decimal numbers (to make it easier to do calculations):

**B4 DC F4** -> (180, 220, 247)

Now consider how far these values are from white (255,255,255)

(255, 255, 255) - (180, 220, 247) = (75, 35, 8)

If that's the difference at 50%, then at 100% the difference should be twice as much (transparency is just linear interpolation).

(75, 35, 8) x 2 = (150,70,16)

That's the difference from white. So subtract this from white, and convert back to hex:

(255,255,255) - (150, 70, 16) = (105, 185, 239) -> **69B9DF**